# UPS Germany delaying payment indefinitely

Tags: germany, payment

UPS charged me a brokerage fee when I shipped a parcel from England to Germany. It was a huge amount (113.29 euros) and didn't make sense since my parcel should not have been charged any customs fee. I had to initially pay this amount because the deliver driver refused to give me the parcel unless I did. After much back and forth about it, I received the following email from them.

> We acknowledge receipt of your message and apologize for the wait.
>
> Due to the situations described, we will assume the total amount of
> EUR 113,29 incurred in the interest of an amicable settlement without
> acknowledging any legal obligation and without prejudice to the
> factual and legal situation.
>
> If you have already paid the bill, please send an email (including
> your bank details and the number of the credit note) to
> gbsarde@ups.com on. Please wait for the credit, as the colleagues are unable to take
> action.

It's now been a month and a half since that email and after multiple follow ups, I still haven't got either the money or any deadline by which I should get the money back. What do I do to get someone to actually pay back what UPS has promised to pay in a reasonable time period?

Comment: I wouldn't see six weeks as 'indefinitely.' But the next step would be to send the demand in writing, by registered mail.